# Find longest common subsequences with minimum number of subsequences

Tags: string, algorithm, subsequence, lcs

Given two strings, I would like to find the longest common subsequences with minimum breaks.
For e.g:

```
String 1 = abce
String 2 = abbde
```

The longest common subsequences is abe with legth = 3
However I would like to get case (1) instead of (2) because there are the least number of subsequences. How could I achieve this? Thank you.

```
(1) ABcE and ABbdE => AB-E : 2 subsequences
(2) ABcE and AbBbE => A-B-E : 3 subsequences
```

(The common subsequences are in uppercases just for illustration)

Comment: In your detection code, simply save the index for the common sequence that has the fewest breaks?